# How can I add the "automated mailer task cron job"?

Tags: civimail, cron-job

I'm sorry guys,  I have really no idea what I'm doing. I'm just trying to learn as I go. 
I've been checking out forums and videos and it all leads me to this: I need to know the command so I can add the cron job from my cpanel, so that my civiCRM starts sending the emails.
I have already enabled the option "process_mailing" on scheduled jobs settings.
Sorry I'm so lost... hope any of you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is some general information about scheduling jobs and running cron here [User and Administrator Guide](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs.html).

You will find links to more details in both the guide and the link (Job parameters and command line syntax documentation…) on the Administer=>System Settings=>Scheduled Jobs.  Here is that link [Managing Scheduled Jobs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-Command-lineSyntaxforRunningJobs).

There a number of different ways to run the jobs from cron and a number of examples in the second link, which should take you to the command line syntax part of the page.

This command line should work in most situations; though, there can be better options for security, etc. depending on your environment.

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/civcrm/module/bin/cli.php -s site -u user -p password -e Job -a execute
```

The -s parameter is the site name, and defaults to 'localhost'. It should be set the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) of your site (eg, 'example.com') Some jobs rely on this being set (in certain cases, the CiviMail mailing scheduler uses this FQDN to generate absolute URLs when relative URLs are in the email).

For the crontab challenged folks (most of us at some point), the */15 says to run it every 15 mins.